# What are the available snowflake editions?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

If I read the documentation, it says that there are 4 editions. But in some of the blogs and articles, I see that there is a premier edition also. Is premier edition really available?

**Overview of Editions**

1. Standard Edition
2. Enterprise Edition
3. Business Critical Edition
4. Virtual Private Snowflake (VPS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was just a renaming some time ago. The current editions are the ones you mentioned and can be found here https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/intro-editions.html :-)

When I remember correctly in the past it was Standard, Premier, Enterprise, Business Critical and Virtual Private Snowflake. The difference between Standard and Premier was the level of support. The higher support-level is now also offered within Standard and thus Premier isn't necessary anymore. (A hint can be found at the very bottom in the footnote of the link above ;-)